# Calculating content Size of Table View with dynamic increasing cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to calculate the tableView's content size height which has dynamic increasing cells. For that I am writing code as -

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MostLikedTVCscnd
            cell.image.image = imageArr[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
            cell.aboutLbl.text = labelArr[indexPath.row] as? String


let contentSizeHeight  = tableView.contentSize.height//But here I am not getting the proper height

return cell

}
```

I checked an answer in the question for calculating tableView content size - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17939938/5395919   which reads

> Note for those for whom this isn't working -- tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath messes with contentSize, so you might have luck just by removing your implementation of it. – weienw

**So is there any means in which I can get correct content size despite dynamic cell size?**

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for this problem? I've faced the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use key value observing (KVO) to be notified whenever the table view’s content size changes. This may or may not work for what you’re trying to do. I’m just not clear on what you’re looking to obtain, but I don’t think it would be good to try to use that in cellForRowAtIndexPath.