# CellForRowAt doesn't calling after changing tableview height

Tags: swift, uitableview, constants

When i load data from database and call first time `tableView.reloadData()` and `tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height` it works perfect. But when i add new cell and do it again, it doesn't works. without `tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height` works but then i can't change height of `tableView`. it is important to change `tableView` height.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is not a simple UIScrollView, its ContentSize from cells in the current view screen, not all cells.

If you add a cell out the current view bounds, it will not change the ContentSize.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958328/when-does-a-uitableviews-contentsize-get-set