# Get UITableView contentSize after insert/delete rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to achieve `tableViewCell` is selected then insert some rows. Select again then delete these rows. The method like below:

```
func animateRows(tableView: UITableView, insert: Bool, indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        if (insert) {
            tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        } else {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
        print(tableView.contentSize)
        tableView.reloadData()
        print(tableView.contentSize)
    }
```

This method works well. I want to get the `contentSize` after insert or delete action ends. Then reset the tableView's content size. But the only way i found is after call `tableView.reloadData()` the contentSize was updated. But feel not proper. Any other good solutions?

**EDIT**:

> What are you doing with contentSize of a UITableView anyways?

I need the `contentSize` to make the `tableView` height fit the content. Actually my tableView is one subView of UIScrollView. I need the `tableView` show all rows all the time. Then layout `scrollView` `contentSize` properly.

Comment: What are you doing with contentSize of a UITableView anyways?

Comment: I need contentSize to resize `tableView` frame to make it fit content. See more on edit. thanks.

Comment: try this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34518445/3901620