# Tableviewcell height with inside tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableView in which every cell contains another tableView with dynamic row height.
My question is how can I set the row height of the first table to fit the height of the inner tableView?
I'm using this code but it does not work as it should.

```
var heights: [CGFloat] = []
var loades: [Bool] = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

      return self.heights[indexPath.row]

}



 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell

        cell.date.text = ev.date

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.event = ev

        self.heights[indexPath.row] = cell.tv.frame.height

        if self.loades[indexPath.row] == false{

            self.loades[indexPath.row] = true
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }

        return cell}
```

Comment: Firstly get a global variable for height. Second add a observer to the child table view to get the Content size of child table after load/ reload the child table. And In cell for row at index path, load the child table. In observe you will get the Content size of child table view. Assign the content size height in global height variable then reload main table view.

Comment: @Krimi thanks, how can I add an observer to the child tableView?

Comment: Please look into this example  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34518445/3070139

Comment: @Krimi thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'd try getting the nested tableview's contentSize in your heightForRow method.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can access to your `tableview.contentSize.height`, the contentSize gets the value of all tableview content if your tableview is dynamic, the content of this height you can divide in the number of rows what you have. This is just a simply solution, some like this:

```
let size = tableView.contentSize.height
let cellSize = size / models.count
```

where models is the array of objects printed in tableviewcell inside tableview

Recommend:
Put a height constraint inside your cell to your tableView, and try to refresh with de sizeCell sum

```
cell.tableViewInsideCell.reloadData()
cell.heightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
```

and set

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```