# UITableView with dynamic height inside UIScrollView:

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a screen with `UINavigationController` and `UITabBar`.
The `UINavigationController` screen is a `UIView` (in figure below, in red), that haves an image in the top and a `UIScrollView` (in figure below, in green). The `UIScrollView` have two `UILabel` ("Some text") and a `UITableView` that DO NOT ENABLE SCROLLING.

[image]

Every time the list become bigger, i need to enlarge the tableview height, dynamically. At the same time, I think I need to enlarge the `UIScrollView`. See the image below:

[image]

How can I define the dynamical height to `UITableView` and `UIScrollView`?

**My goal is:** Every time the list become bigger, the `UIScrollView` become bigger too.

**My environment:**

- My UITableView DO NOT ENABLE SCROLLING
- I am using XCode 4.6 and the view is a FreeForm
- My view is using AutoLayout

I tried to do this setting just the [UItableview height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801074/uitableview-content-height), without success.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Why do you want to nest a tableview inside a scrollview? Just for the two labels? Can't you just add the two labels to the tableview as header view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the height of table view bin the method

```
heightForCellAtIndexPath:
```

in this method you pass the height of each row in this you can calculate height by creating a globale variable and in this variable add the row height each time.

or you can find it by having no of rows * height of a row in height of a row is constant.

may this will help you.