# Get TableView Content Size Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i want to set height constraint to my `UITableView` so i can stretch it.
The problem is that im not getting accurate reading with `tableView.contentSize.height`.
My table has 10 rows when each is 40px height.
`tableView.contentSize.height` reads as 388 while
10 * 40 (which is the actual height is 400)

what am i missing here?
thanks

Comment: How is your table view setup? The table view's `contentSize` will be correct once the table view has been displayed assuming you are not using any estimated row heights.

Comment: @rmaddy it is using estimated row height. but im calling reloadData before which is synchronous

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `contentSize` (as being a property of `UIScrollView`, which `UITableView` inherits from and *uses*) does not have its final value until later, probably because table cells are loaded dynamically. Instead you can calculate the correct height yourself.

[Here is one way of doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7804249/4543629)